# Slow Performance When Using Scalaz Task

Tags: scala, scalaz

I'm looking to improve the performance of a Monte Carlo simulation I am developing.

I first did an implementation which does the simulation of each paths sequentially as follows:

```
def simulate() = {
  for (path <- 0 to 30000) {
    (0 to 100).foreach(
      x => // do some computation
    )    
  }
}
```

This basically is simulating 30,000 paths and each path has 100 discretised random steps.

The above function runs very quickly on my machine (about 1s) for the calculation I am doing.

I then thought about speeding it up even further by making the code run in a multithreaded fashion.

I decided to use `Task` for this and I coded the following:

```
val simulation = (1 |-> 30000 ).map(n => Task {
  (1 |-> 100).map(x => // do some computation)
  })
```

I then use this as follows:

```
Task.gatherUnordered(simulation).run
```

When I kick this off, I know my machine is doing a lot of work as I can
see that in the activity monitor and also the machine fan is going ballistic.
After about two minutes of heavy activity on the machine, the work it seems
to be doing finishes but I don't get any value returned (I am expected a collection
of Doubles from each task that was processed).

My questions are:

1. Why does this take longer than the sequential example? I am more
   than likely doing something wrong but I can't see it.
2. Why don't I get any returned collection of values from the tasks that are apparently being processed?

Comment: Looks like `Task.gatherUnordered` is implemented inefficiently. The total time is `O(N^2)`, where `N` is the number of tasks in the list.

Comment: In general, depending on the speed of individual calculations, 100*30000 operations may be a too small target for parallelization for a modern CPU.

Comment: @mikołak, true, but this simulation will be run for a basket of products. I just wanted to get the semantics right for one product first.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why `Task.gatherUnordered` is so slow, but if you change `Task.gatherUnordered` to `Nondeterminism.gatherUnordered` everything will be fine:

```
import scalaz.Nondeterminism

Nondeterminism[Task].gatherUnordered(simulation).run
```

I'm going to create an issue on Github about `Task.gatherUnordered`. This definitely should be fixed.